# Abstract Method vs Listener

Tags: java

I'm making a button class that handles input and drawing by itself; the only thing that needs to be defined is the location and what happens when the button is pressed.

In this situation, would it be better to have a `ButtonPressListener` interface and have it as a parameter in `Button`'s constructor, or should the `Button` be abstract with the abstract method `pressed()`?

The resulting initiation code for `Button` would be like the following:

```
new Button(x,y,new ButtonPressListener(){
    @Override
    protected void pressed(){
        // code
    }
});
```

or

```
new Button(x,y){
    @Override
    protected void pressed(){
        // code
    }
};
```

Also, in other similar situations, what should be considered when choosing between the two approaches?

Thanks.

Comment: The listener is more flexible, as any class can implement the interface and get notified of the press. And you could extend it with an 'addButtonPressListener' so that you could have more than one listener.

Comment: The old saying is: prefer composition over inheritance. Especially with single inheritance as in java, pushing stuff into an abstract class forces you into a box pretty much; and normally it doesn't take long before that box becomes to small... . So, by default: don't do that; unless you have a very clear understanding why it would be better than anything else ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the listener.

Resons:

- The listener will give you more flexability, when using java8 lambdas.
- You can write one class that listens to several buttons
- You can write one class that listens to a button and inherits some other class

By the way: You should consider using a setter, rather then a parameter of the constructor. This will allow to create buttons without listeners - or define more than one listener. Also parameters are a little bit harder to read then setter, as parameters cannot have names in java.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to learn from this project, you might as well do both at the same time and find out what works better for you. Wenn you found out, refactor and throw out the less liked option.

Make a default implementation of `Button.pressed()` that calls the function of your listener implementation if set. Supply two constructors, one that sets the listener and one that does not.

Of course that is not an option is others shall use this API.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'd agree with @slartidan, but I'll try it out for myself!